# WiX Custom action not executing

Tags: c#, installation, wix, custom-action

I am having trouble with a Wix custom action not executing. The installer continually rolls itself back even when the custom action returns ActionResult.Success.

**Custom Action (C#)**

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SetPermissionsToAppDataFolder(Session session)
{
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

**Custom Action Definition in Wix**

```
<!-- Custom Action -->
<Binary Id="CustomActionLibrary" SourceFile="$(var.CustomActionFolder)InstallerCustomActions.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="CustomActionInstallDirectoryPermission"
              BinaryKey="CustomActionLibrary"
              DllEntry="SetPermissionsToAppDataFolder"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check" />
```

**Install sequence calling the custom action**

```
<!-- Install Sequences -->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="CustomActionInstallDirectoryPermission" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The installer compiles fine so there is no problem finding the custom action library file. The issue is that the installer gets to the final stage of installation before rolling back. When we remove the call to the custom action in the install sequence the installer completes.

From my understanding the custom action CA.dll gets embedded into the final installer. Initially I'd thought the CA.dll needed to be distributed alongside the installer but later discovered the installer compiles it into the final .msi.

I have "wired" the custom action library using the code found at:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132918/Creating-Custom-Action-for-WIX-Written-in-Managed

No matter what I do I cannot get the installer to complete, even when the custom action returns "success". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Execute `msiexec /i yourinstaller.msi /l log.txt` and look for any errors in the outputted `log.txt` file that is generated.

Comment: Will the log file be created relative to the installer?

Comment: The log file will be created in the directory that `msiexec` is executed from. Perhaps something like `C:\Users\Rupert Puxton\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\My Project\Installer\bin\Release`, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling with WiX and who stumbled here.

A few suggestions :

1) Have you tried adding *Debugger.Launch()* to the first line of your CustomAction code (i.e. above the *Return ActionResult.Success;* )? If you don't get a dialog box asking to launch a debugger, then you know your WiX script is not referring to your CA.dll correctly or there's a problem with its invocation.

2) If you are using *Fragments* and the CustomAction elements sit inside them, try taking them out and put them under the *Product* element instead.

3) If you're going to use deferred execution, have you tried *Impersonate="no"* attribute in your CustomAction